# save value input dynamic form jquery

Tags: jquery

I have problem with my script because I want save value in "input" when i refresh page. Under i show excerpt my code.

```
function addControls()
{
    console.log(x);
    if (x < max_fields_limit) 
    { 
        x++; // Increment counter
        setCookie("countControls1",x,100);
        $('.input_fields_container').append('<div><input id="input" name="name[]" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko:" type="text" value="'+val+'"/><a href="#" class="delete" >Usuń</a></div>'); // Add input field
}
}
```

Comment: what is the problem exacly? are you getting errors, is it just not working?

Comment: Adds new "input" fields and types some text into them. Then reloads the form that is made in php, the data in the inputs are deleted.